# How to split one excel cell into two cells using java

Tags: java, excel

I have spreadsheet and I need to spit the content of one cell into two cells.

The cell content like this. 
Name 19:00:00

I need to split it into two cells as Name and 19:00:00

I'm using apache poi to read excel file. Are there any better library to read the excel file and work with it. I need to delete several columns from the datasheet.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Apache poi is a good choice for that task.

Answer (score 0):

*You could do something likewise,*

> **step 1 :** read value which is in your case is : "Name 19:00:00" into one temporary String,
>
> **step 2 :** unmerge cell using apache poi's workSheet.removeMergedRegion(index - of the region to unmerge). [refer this.](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#removeMergedRegion%28int%29)
>
> **step 3 :** split string what you received into step-1, from space, so you get array of String which is most likely, ary[0] = Name ,
>   ary[1](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#removeMergedRegion%28int%29) = 19:00:00
>
> **step 4 :** write ary[0] into unmerged first cell and likewise for another one as per you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
public class Readsheet 
{
   static XSSFRow row;
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
   {
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
      new File("G:\\test.xlsx"));
      XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
      XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
      Iterator < Row > rowIterator = spreadsheet.iterator();
      while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
      {
         row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
         Iterator < Cell > cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
         while ( cellIterator.hasNext()) 
         {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
               case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
               System.out.print( 
               cell.getNumericCellValue() + " ; " );
               break;
               case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
               System.out.print(
               cell.getStringCellValue() + " ; " ); 
               break;
               default:
            }
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
      fis.close();
   }
}
```

This is the code I used to read excel file.